# What caused different output with wrapfigure?

Tags: positioning, typography, wrapfigure

I'm currently writing a Beginner's Guide to LaTeX and I tried this code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\graphicspath{{../images/}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{some awesome title}
    \blindtext\footnote{some footnote}

    \begin{framed}
        some text with a \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{some label to mask URL}
    \end{framed}

    \section{some fancy title}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5,keepaspectratio,draft]{system-spec}
        \caption{some very long caption over two lines long. Yes it is a very long caption}
        \label{img:fancypic}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    some text with a \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{some label to mask URL} \keys{JA}
    \blindtext\footnote{another footnote}

    \begin{framed}
        some text with a \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{some label to mask URL}
    \end{framed}

\end{document}
```

---

The output is smooth and clear as expected.

> [image: desired output]

But when I use the code in the actual document I get this:

> [image: output from actual]

---

**EDIT** taking the comment into account:
The image in the second picture is more at the bottom of the page and not aligned to the title of the section. I would like to know how to align that properly as tested.

---

**EDIT2** source for second part:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\graphicspath{{../images/}}

\begin{document}
\chapter[Installationsanleitung]{Installation {\LaTeX}-Compiler \& Editor}
\label{chp:install}

Um {\LaTeX} verwenden zu können, werden folgende zwei wesentliche Komponenten benötigt: der Compiler und ein Editor.

Als Empfehlung für einen Editor, wird {\TeX studio} in diesem Guide vorgestellt, da die IDE\abk{IDE}{Integrated Development Environment}\footnote{Integrated Development Environment. Laienhaft ausgedrückt, programmieren Sie Ihr Dokument.} einen hohen Komfort bietet. Näheres dazu in \autoref{sec:texstudio}. Welcher Compiler einsetzt wird, hängt vom eingesetzten Betriebssystem ab. Im nachfolgenden wird die Installation des Compilers auf den gängigsten End-User-OS\abk{OS}{Operating System}\footnote{OS: Operating System. dt.: Betriebssystem} beschrieben.

\begin{framed}
    Plattformunabhängige Alternative zu allen genannten Versionen: \href{https://www.dante.de/tex/tl-install-windows/installation-einfach.html}{ {\TeX~Live}}
\end{framed}
\section[HowTo {{MiK\TeX} \& Windows}]{Installation von {MiK\TeX} unter Windows}
\label{sec:miktex}

MiK{\TeX} ist eine der für Windows erhältlichen {\LaTeX}-Distributionen und am weitesten verbreitet. Daneben gibt es beispielsweise noch pro{\TeX}t, eine Weiterentwicklung, welche {\TeX}studio als IDE mitbringt.
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{system-spec.png}
    \caption[Systemtyp ermitteln]{Das hier gezeigte Windows 7 ist ein 64bit System. Prüfen Sie vor der Installation, welche Version in Frage kommt.}
    \label{img:sys-spec}
\end{wrapfigure}
{MiK\TeX} liegt aktuell in der Version 2.9 vor und stellt in der Grundausstattung alle Pakete zur Verfügung um einfache Dokumente zu setzen. Den etwa 180MB großen Windows-Installer finden Sie \href{http://miktex.org/download}{hier}.

Computerhardware und Betriebssysteme der letzten fünf Jahre basieren meist auf einer 64-Bit-Architektur. Wenn Sie unsicher sind, worauf Ihr Computer oder Betriebssystem läuft, verwenden Sie die abwärtskompatible 32bit-Version.

Nach dem Download wird die Installation per Doppelklick auf \emph{basic-miktex-<version-nummer>.exe} ausgeführt.

Bestätigen Sie die Sicherheitsfrage mit \keys{JA} und folgen Sie den Bildschirmanweisungen. In \autoref{sec:texstudio} stehen die Anweisungen, wie {\TeX}studio  installiert wird.

\begin{framed}
    Eine ausführliche Installationsanleitung zu {MiK\TeX} (auf Englisch) finden sie \href{http://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex}{hier}.
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

There's no error or warning in the typeset process. It just looks different. I can live with that when it comes to publishing it, but I'd like to know if and how there's any way of improving it.

Thanks in advance.

I provide the image I used:

> [image: image used]

Comment: your question is very unclear, what exactly "looks different" (apart from the fact that it's different words in a different language) If you want anyone to test anything you probably should post the code for the second document?

Comment: i agree with @DavidCarlisle -- the font is the same style and size as for the rest of the insert, and the columns and baselines are aligned  properly.  the only "difference" or "inconsistency" i can see is that numerals look different from words.  i really don't know what else to look for.

Comment: You _have not shown the code_ but it looks like the wrapfig in the first case is on the first paragraph after the section, and in the second document it is on the second paragraph. _but how do you expect anyone to debug unseen code just from an image of the output!!!!_

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry for the delay. I provided the code now.

Comment: please make the second one a complete document that reproduces the problem, it can not be run as is but probably you just want to move the wrapfig before that paragraph if you want the cutout to start after the heading

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks to your proverbial kick in the butt, I rearranged the passage in question and it now it almost looks like it.

Comment: Put the `wrapfigure` environment just after the `\section`  command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

**EDIT2**: As it turned out, I misunderstood the proper use of `{...}` with respect to `wrapfigure`. As the `wrapfigure`-manual clearly states, it should not be put between groupings of any sort.

---

I found out that typing `{MiK\TeX}` or `{Mac\TeX}` was the reason why the typeset in that particular passage was causing the output I complained about. While dabbling with rearranging the code section I encountered missing linebreaks in lines with such code.

Once I changed it to `MiK{\TeX}` resp. `Mac{\TeX}` the desired output was generated.

I seems to me, that the parentheses have to be enclosing the logo commands only instead of the whole name.

**EDIT**

output with `{MiK\TeX}`:

[image]

output with `MiK{\TeX}`:

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I would say so too, but as I experienced the lines weren't broken approriately when the former was used. beats me, why this happened.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: first I thought it might have been caused by a rogue `\href`. I just tried what happens if I change the parts mentioned above. I did not change anything else besides putting the image before the first paragraph.

Comment: oh of course, i see now.  it is nothing to do with the logo really. In one case you are starting the paragraph inside a local group (which wrapfig explicitly does not support) you would see the same with `Hello` and `{Hello}` I'll delete the first comment (even though it's true, it has to be interpreted with care in this case:-)

Comment: The moral is: *never start a paragraph with something inside braces*

Comment: @egreg yeah, well. it's something I can mention in the guide's section about reserved symbols in LaTeX.